# heroku 1st time push encounters an error that rejects the push i tried to do

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm fairly new to Ruby and I tried to push my code to Heroku, but it seems that when I tried:

```
git push heroku master
```

It failed in the push and displayed this error:

```
Bundle completed (25.17s)
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
   -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   DEPRECATION WARNING: Paths in SQLite3 database URLs of the form `sqlite3:///path` will be treated as absolute in Rails 4.2. Please switch to `sqlite3:dbname`. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/Rakefile:6)
   rake aborted!
   Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:190:in `rescue in spec'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:187:in `spec'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:118:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
   /tmp/build_9b82245b019e78f91f12b14e50aeac25/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    !
    !     Precompiling assets failed.
    !

    !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

   To git@heroku.com:rigpirate.git
    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:testapp.git'
```

This is what it displayed after I submitted the push command to Heroku. I think it is because of my code in the gem file here:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
group :development, :test do 
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'y
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
```

Can anybody help me with this one?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you put the `sqlite3` gem inside the `development` and `test` groups. If you'd want to deploy with sqlite3 on Heroku, you need to include it in the production group as well, which is as simple as removing the `group :development, :test`.

Do note that using sqlite3 on Heroku is most likely a bad idea, and you would be better off using Heroku Postgres. [Read the Heroku documentation for more information](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3).

Comment: hi thanks for the info but already got it up and running! but it required me to install libpq-dev so i did that and so i finally installed the pg and then send it to heroku

Answer (score 0):

after a while of searching i saw the answer here

```
 http://ryanbigg.com/2014/10/ubuntu-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you//
```

I just needed to install PG and then do a

sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

and then the push to heroku worked